# Ant fail and exit if current build has compile errors

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build

I have an antscript called devbuild.xml. This script just deploys my files to 1 tomcat and 2 karaf instances, without calling javac or anything like that. The build itself to compile the code happens through the Project -> Build Automatically menu option using the default java builder. The script itself can be called through the External Tools Configuration in 2 ways (with or without an optional step enabled).

However, I've had a couple of times now where I've accidentally deployed to Tomcat while my code has compile errors (the red x in the project explorer on the files with errors). I'd like to avoid this in the future by checking if the build that's currently being deployed has files, but preferably without having to rebuild the entire project.

So essentially, I want to check the latest build of the entire project for compile-time errors at the start of the deploy without having to all check them manually, and cancel the deploy if there are any errors. Is this possible?

Comment: You could use the [`<touch>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html) to touch files when an Ant build begins and when a build completes successfully. For example, `<touch file="build.begin"/>` when the build begins and `<touch file="build.done"/>` when the build completes successfully. When deploying, your Ant script can check that `build.done` is newer than `build.done`.

Comment: @ChadNouis That requires a custom build script, though, which means I could just as well call the `<javac>` task in my antscript with a failonerror. The build itself in the Build Automatically window is just the default Java builder.

Comment: you can use `javac` task in your ant build xml, which will compile your source code and will fail thebuild if code is not compilable

Comment: @Sanjeev That's the thing: I'd prefer to do it without using the `javac` task. I mean, it's already compiled, why can't I just check the most recent compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Beside the existing `Java Builder` you may use an `Ant Builder` that runs after the Java Builder. `Project / Properties / Builder / New Ant Builder`
To check if the Java Builder copmpiled correctly, use some [condition](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) in your Ant script.
To make sure all works as expected you should consider compiling with Ant [javac](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) Task, as Eclipse JDT Compiler and Javac behave differently, f.e. when dealing with Generics.